# laravel : After delete record from database the new record is in the place of the deleted record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have 10 records in my table when i delete record 5 and create new record the new record come in the place of the deleted record like this :

before delete record the ids its :
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

after delete record 5 and insert new record the id its 11 and the place it: 
1
2
3
4
11
6
7
8
9
10

fetch data code :

```
$permissions = Permission::all();
```

delete code:

```
$permission = Permission::find($id)->delete();
```

create code:

```
Permission::create($request->all());
```

records in table : 
[image]

records in database : 
[image]

Comment: How do you fetch data from db?

Comment: To explicitly set order, try orderBy('id')

Comment: my problem not with order nope , my problem in table records

Comment: where are you viewing rows? how are you fetching rows?

Comment: i update my question , you can see the image of records

Comment: what r you using as query to get  the records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an `orderBy`, it's up to your database to decide the order. Database engines may handle this differently, so if it matters to you what order they're in, **you** need to tell the database that.

An explicit `orderBy('id')` (or another column, if it makes more sense for your app) in your database calls will ensure it's always in the order you expect.

Comment: but this is the first time with this problem, i build many projects with laravel i never seen this problem before

Comment: i solved problem with change Storage Engine from (MyISAM) to (InnoDB)

Comment: Yes, but the issue within Laravel would be resolved with the answer posted here.  The viewing of the order is different from how it sits in the database.

Comment: @iFahdDev None of that really matters. Without an `orderBy`, order isn't guaranteed. If it's important to you, set an order.

Comment: @ceejayoz you mean that can happen without `orderBy` ?

Comment: If you don't tell it what order to put them in, it can return them in any order at all. The fact that they usually come back in something close to numerical order is basically a coincidence.